# SQL DML how to combine value from other row after using count, sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my code:

```
select CustomerName, count(td.bikeid) as [Total Transactions], sum(quantity) as [Total Bikes Bought],
replace(customerphone, '0', '+62') as [Customer Phone]
from MsCustomer mc join TransactionHeader th
on mc.CustomerID = th.CustomerID join TransactionDetail td
on th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID join MsBike mb
on td.BikeID = mb.BikeID
group by td.BikeID, td.TransactionID, CustomerName, Quantity, CustomerPhone
having sum(Quantity) > 5 and count(th.transactionid) between 2 and 5
```

and the result is this
[image]
How can I make it so that the total transactions and bikes bought of the same customername got summed up, for example of the result I want:
(cendana, 2, 16, +6283859786138)

Comment: Please don't post images of data, but enough sample data that other users would be able to reproduce the problem that you are encountering. Refer to the guidelines for creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Your GROUP BY clause seems the culprit here. Usually, all the ungrouped columns from SELECT list will go into GROUP BY clause but you have multiple columns in GROUP BY clause without using them in SELECT list. Using those unnecessary columns in GROUP BY clasue is causing this issue. Just get rid of those columns, And you probably get your result -

```
SELECT CustomerName, 
       COUNT(td.bikeid) AS [Total Transactions], 
       SUM(quantity) AS [Total Bikes Bought],
       REPLACE(customerphone, '0', '+62') AS [Customer Phone]
  FROM MsCustomer mc 
  JOIN TransactionHeader th ON mc.CustomerID = th.CustomerID 
  JOIN TransactionDetail td ON th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID 
  JOIN MsBike mb ON td.BikeID = mb.BikeID
 GROUP BY CustomerName, CustomerPhone
HAVING SUM(Quantity) > 5 
   AND COUNT(th.transactionid) BETWEEN 2 AND 5;
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much sir, hope you have a successful life